# How do I create an inverse relationship for a User when I'm only allowed to save the currently logged in user?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

My User class has a many-to-many relationship with the Convos class. I want to add `user` (which is a `PFUser *` that is *not the current logged-in user*) to `convo` object, and I want to add `convo` to the `user` object for the inverse relation.

```
PFRelation *relation = [self.convo relationforKey:@"users"];
[relation addObject:user];

[self.convo save];

PFRelation *inverseRelation = [user relationforKey:@"convos"];
[inverseRelation addObject:self.convo];
[user save];
```

The problem is that I am not allowed to save `user` because apparently I can only save the currently logged-in user. Here is the error:

> User cannot be saved unless they have been authenticated via logIn or signUp

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way I can think of would be to have a separate PFObject which owns the Convos relation.  For e.g.

```
PFUser["proxy"] -> PFObject["convos"] -> PFRelation
```

Your code would then become:

```
PFObject *relation = [self.convo relationforKey:@"users"];
[relation addObject:user];

PFObject *userProxy = [user objectForKey:@"proxy"];

// N.B. You need to make sure this object exists already, and create it if not
// N.B. Make sure you include this key when you query for the user, or you'll need to load the data here
if (userProxy == nil) NSAssert(nil, @"Need to create the users Proxy object");
if (userProxy.isDataAvailable == NO) NSAssert(nil, @"Need to include the Proxy object key in the user query");


PFRelation *inverseRelation = [userProxy relationforKey:@"convos"];
[inverseRelation addObject:self.convo];

[PFObject saveObjects:@[self.convo, userProxy]];
```